Video of someone who died in hospital but came back
There was a video going round on Google Videos, way back before Youtube was big or owned by Google, like in 2006ish? It was a video of an Israeli man, sitting with sfarim behind him, giving an account of how he died on the hospital bed, had an experience of going to be judged, while crying his eyes out, and explaining how he was given a chance to come back and try again. He was secular before this event, and is now full on black hat and peyot.
I haven't seen this video for years, it was in Hebrew and had subtitles. It spoke about all the legions of accusing angels that were arrayed before him, from his spilling seed, as well as "Olam HaCopy" - a copy world in shamayim (a well known Kabbalistic concept, although of course it's not called Olam HaCopy - I just remember that's what he called it).
Does anyone know where I can see this video today?

I think Rav Alon Anava is the gentlman you're trying to find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpflBfazqUc

@יהושעק nope, but sounds interesting, thanks for sharing

I think this is what you're looking for:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=c0Ns3D6Tpfs&list=PLF0951299C016A9EB&index=2&pp=iAQB
On YouTube it's divided into several parts, linked above is pt. 1 within a playlist. "Olam HaCopy" is mentioned in pt. 3, min. 7:03.

It's funny, the first time I saw this, I didn't know who the Ben Ish Chai was. When I learned about him later, I didn't make the connection, until this rewatch
